# React: Changing Firebase path dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to change firebase path on button click. The old connection disconnects but new connection doesn't establishes. Below is the instance of code I'm using.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import firebase from "./firebase";

class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      path: "someDirectory1/subDirectory"
    };
    this.changePath = this.changePath.bind(this);
  }

  changePath() {
    this.setState({ path: "/someDirectory2/subDirectory" });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ChildComponent path={this.state.path} />
        <button onClick={this.changePath}>Change path</button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mountRef: firebase.database().ref(this.props.path + "/path2")
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref(this.props.path + "/path1");
    ref.once("value", snapshot => {
      var data = snapshot.val();
      //Some functionality
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var ref = this.state.mountReference;
    ref.on("value", snapshot => {
      var snapshotData = snapshot.val();
      //some functionality
    });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.path !== this.props.path) {
      this.state.mountReference.off("value");
      var ref = firebase.database().ref(nextProps.path);
      this.setState({ path: nextProps.path, ref });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {/* {Some rendering} */}
        {/* {Some rendering} */}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

If I add [componentWillUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate) and [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) for listening to new path, the listener goes into infinite loop. If I use [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate), then it's being called multiple times initially as other states are being changed in the parent component and data doesn't renders as the condition `nextProps.path!==this.props.path` returns `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution for the multiple paths.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import firebase from "./firebase";

class ChildComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mountRef: firebase.database().ref(this.props.path + "/path2")
    };
    this.oneTimeListen = this.oneTimeListen.bind(this);
    this.asyncListen = this.asyncListen.bind(this);
  }



  componentWillMount() {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref(this.state.path + "/path1");
    this.oneTimeListen(this.props.path, ref);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var ref = this.state.mountReference;
    this.asyncListen(ref);
  }



  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.path !== this.props.path) {
      this.state.mountReference.off("value");

      // initial listen
      var ref = firebase.database().ref(nextProps.path + "/path1");
      this.setState({ path: nextProps.path });
      this.oneTimeListen(nextProps.path, ref);

      // listens to changes
      ref = firebase.database().ref(nextProps.path + "/path2");
      this.asyncListen(ref, true);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Listens to path only for one time initially.
   * @param {String} path - firebase path
   * @param {Object} ref - firebase reference variable
   */
  oneTimeListen(path, ref) {
    ref.once("value", snapshot => {
      var data = snapshot.val();
      //functionality
  }


  /**
   * Listens continuously to changed values
   * @param {Object} ref - firebase reference variable
   * @param {Boolean} setNewRef - if true, change this.state.mountReference, (only true, when firebase path changes)
   */

  asyncListen(ref, setNewRef) {
    ref.on("value", snapshot => {
      var snapshotData = snapshot.val();
      //functionality

      if (setNewRef) {
         this.setState({ mountReference: ref });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {/* {Some rendering} */}
        {/* {Some rendering} */}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

`oneTimeListen()` is used for initial listen to `path1`.

`asyncListen()` is used for listening continuously on `path2`.

Whenever a new path is received `componentWillReceiveProps()` calls `oneTimeListen()` and `asyncListen()` and send the new reference to the respective functions.

Comment: This seems like an over-engineered solution. Putting everything in a function that toggles between the paths based on a boolean value in state would be easier to test. It is also a lot more reusable, you can have the paths and boolean as parameters if you wanted to. Is there a reason you did not take to my solution above? Was there something it did not address.

Comment: @JoshPittman Actually I implemented this even before you answered. Yet to test your code.

Comment: @JoshPittman another thing, click is coming from the parent component, not from the same component. We'll have to check when the props changes. And that could only be checked using `componentWillReceiveProps()`.
Try considering the case using `ref.on()` instead of `ref.once()` or both.

Comment: You can just pass your onClick function down as a prop. Regarding on/once you used on in your example. If you wanted the reads to stay open for real-time updates this wasn't explicit in your question, you should update your question. I don't understand why you asked the question if you already had a response. That seems like a waste of other people's time.

Comment: @JoshPittman I found the solution like 5 hours after I posted the question. Regarding on/once, check the code both are there. Also I mentioned I'm able to close the previous connection.

Comment: I'm confused, have you figured a solution or are you still looking for help? If the problem is solved, you should mark your response accepted for others. If you still need help, please explain and I'll do what I can.

Comment: @JoshPittman chill, my problem is solved. Thanks for your answer as well. The reason why answer is not marked as accepted because I can only do it after 24 hrs.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to the path to change on Click you should stay away from the lifecycle methods and put your logic into a function that fires on click. If you want the function to fire once when the component mounts then call it in componentDidMount.

For example:

```
funkyFirebaseFunction() {
 firebase.database()
  .ref(this.props.path + "someDirectory1/subDirectory")
  .once("value", snapshot => {
      var data = snapshot.val();
      //Some functionality
    });
}
```

Then you can repeat the firebase call inside the function, and alternate between the two on the basis of a boolean in state.

```
this.state = {
  clicked: false
}
```

Just make sure you flip the boolean after the firebase call.

```
funkyFirebaseFunction() {
  this.state.clicked ?
     firebase.database()
      .ref(this.props.path + "someDirectory1/subDirectory")
      .once("value", snapshot => {
          var data = snapshot.val();
          //Some functionality
        })
     : firebase.database()
      .ref(this.props.path + "someDirectory2/subDirectory")
      .once("value", snapshot => {
          var data = snapshot.val();
          //Some functionality
        });

     this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked});

    }
```

Then call the function onClick

```
<button onClick={() => this.funkyFirebaseFunction()}>Change path</button>
```

You can pop a reference to it in componnetDidMount if you want it to fire once to begin with.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.funkyFirebaseFunction
}
```